# The Cast option is unable to detect my Windows PC

Tags: applications, 7.1-nougat, screencast, miracast

I am trying to cast my android screen to Windows 10 Connect App, but its not working. I have a [Lenovo K8 Note](http://www3.lenovo.com/in/en/smartphones/smartphone-k-series/Lenovo-K8-Note/p/WMD00000338) running android 7.1.1(not rooted and its near stock OS).

I have an another device with Lineage OS 14.1 (7.1.2) where the Display -> Cast option works properly. But its not working with the Lenovo K8.

I guess google removed the cast support in Nougat for Miracast so users would be forced to use their Chromecast device.

Is there a way to make the cast option to work with Lenovo K8.

Answer (score 0):

I used an app for screen cast to web browser. it uses cast of Mobile device but on PC or any other device I receive the cast on browser